# duda con funcion isset() laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Tengo una inquietud con respecto a la funcion isset, tengo las siguiente lineas.

```
 $usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad", 'danielad')->get();
            $prueba=isset($usuarios);
            dd($prueba);
```

Con esto, la consulta me arroja registros siempre y cuando ese usuario exista, si no existe pues obviamente mente no arroja nada, la duda mia, es que isset en cualquiera de los dos casos me arroja false, y nunca un true... como puedo lograr que esto funcione asi?

Comment: En tu lugar yo haría uso de findOrFail() para primero verificar si el usuario existe, luego dentro de un if(data) si el usuario existe hago el where sino retorno un mensaje indicando que el usuario no existe

Comment: Veo poco lógico y funcional ahí usar isset

Comment: Php7 puedes hacer el operador no null ejemoplo `$prueba = $usuario ?? "No existe;` estos suprimer el uso de isset ya que toma como valor el primer true es decir si no existe $usuario tomara como valor "no existe" puede encadenarde a deseo!

Comment: @zereft recuerda que la solución no va en la zona de tu pregunta, ocupa la zona de respuestas para ello, revertí tu edición, por favor en la zona de respuestas colócalo y ahí explica tu solución

Comment: Ha ok.. ya lo hago.

Answer (score 2):

Antes que nada hay que aclararle a los futuros visitantes de esta pregunta que `isset()` no es una función o helper de Laravel, es una función nativa de PHP y existe desde PHP 4.x

Dicha función sirve para determinar si una variable está definida (o no) y si su valor no es NULL.

Al utilizar Eloquent y su método `get()`, cuando no hay resultados obtenemos algo así:

```
Collection {#705 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

Como se puede ver, es una colección vacía, pero la variable está definida y su valor no es NULL, **por lo cual una comprobación con `isset()` arrojará true**.

---

Si la idea es entregar un false o similar al momento de comprobar si el resultado de una consulta está vacío o no, `findOrFail()` tampoco es la solución, puesto que esta función arroja una excepción en caso que no se encuentre un modelo por su llave primaria. Les dejo como referencia su código fuente:

```
/**
 * Find a model by its primary key or throw an exception.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $id
 * @param  array  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException
 */
public function findOrFail($id, $columns = ['*'])
{
    $result = $this->find($id, $columns);

    if (is_array($id)) {
        if (count($result) == count(array_unique($id))) {
            return $result;
        }
    } elseif (! is_null($result)) {
        return $result;
    }

    throw (new ModelNotFoundException)->setModel(
        get_class($this->model), $id
    );
}
```

---

En este caso la mejor solución es utilizar el método `isNotEmpty()` de las colecciones en Eloquent, el cual entregará `true` si la colección no está vacía, y `false` si está vacía.

```
$usuarios = usuarios::whereUsuarioAd('danielad')->get();

if ($usuarios->isNotEmpty()) {
    // colección no está vacía

} else {
   // colección vacía
}
```

---

Por último, en el código que veo en la respuesta que plantea el mismo OP, NO se están siguiendo las normas de PSR-2, guía de estilo oficial de PHP y de Laravel. Por favor revisar detenidamente el siguiente enlace: https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/

Comment: Gracias por el consejo Shaz

Answer (score 1):

Vamos por partes:

1. `isset()` no te va a ayudar a determinar si un usuario existe, para lo que sirve es para determinar si una variable esta definida; por ejemplo

---

```
$name = "Alfa";

echo isset($name);
```

El código anterior retorna 1, por que la variable tiene un valor asignado

2. Si lo que deseas es retornar valores únicamente si el usuario existe, entonces debes usar de Eloquent el método `find()` o mejor aún `findOrFail()`

---

```
$data = ModelName::findOrFail($userId);
```

Si lo anterior es cierto entonces puedes usar un `if else` para operar la query de este modo

```
$data = ModelName::findOrFail($userId);

if($data){
  $usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad", 'danielad')->get();
  return $usuarios;
}else{
  return "Sin datos";
}
```

Comment: shadow, su solucion es excelente, la aplique, pero despues de estudiarla no me funciono por que tenia una segunda tabla, la cual tenia una segunda columna llamada user_id que debia comparar, igualmente muchas gracias no sabia de findOrFail y sin duda le encontrare utilidad mas adelante.

Answer (score 1):

Esta fue la solucion alternativa.

```html
  public function index(Request $request)
    {

     $registrado = \Auth::user()->tipos_usuarios_id;
     $re = \Auth::user()->id;
     $filtro = \Auth::user()->username;

     if($registrado == 1)

        {
           $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['admin']);
           $usuarios=usuarios::orderBy('id','DESC')->paginate(10);
           $usuariosOpciones =usuarios::pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
           return view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones'));
        }
        
        if($registrado == 2)

          {

            $request->user()->authorizeRoles(['referido']);

            $usuarios=usuarios::where("user_id", $re)->get();
          
        

            if($usuarios->isNotEmpty())
            {

                  $usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad", $filtro)->paginate(10);
                  $elid=usuarios::where("usuario_ad", $filtro)->pluck('user_id')->unique();
                  $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::where('user_id', $elid)->pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
                  return view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones'));

            }
            else
            {

                  $elid=0; 
                  $usuarios=usuarios::where("usuario_ad", $filtro)->paginate(10);
                  $usuariosOpciones=usuarios::where('user_id', $elid)->pluck('usuario_ad', 'user_id')->unique();
                  return view('usuario.index',compact('usuarios','usuariosOpciones'));

            }
       
          }
```